# How to use hibernate with database that have a lot of table

Tags: database, hibernate

I just have experience with some hibernate examples. Now I am jumping into a real project that need to apply hibernate for a database that have more than 100 tables. Hibernate just need to work with around 40 tables (out of more than 100 tables).

Do we have any tool that can generate the mapping and Java object for those tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes look at the [JBOSS tools plug-in](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) for eclipse. You are specifically interested in Reverse Engineering part of the tool

> Reverse Engineering: The most powerful
>   feature of Hibernate Tools is a
>   database reverse engineering tool that
>   can generate domain model classes and
>   Hibernate mapping files, annotated
>   EJB3 entity beans, HTML documentation
>   or even an entire JBoss Seam
>   application in seconds!